# (java.io.IOException) Функция не реализована. Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

Только установил Idea в Ubuntu
при запуске любого main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

}
```

вот такая ошибка

```
Error:Internal error: (java.io.IOException) Функция не реализована
java.io.IOException: Функция не реализована
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(Native Method)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resizeFile(PagedFileStorage.java:358)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resize(PagedFileStorage.java:340)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.expand(ResizeableMappedFile.java:106)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.ensureSize(ResizeableMappedFile.java:75)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.putInt(ResizeableMappedFile.java:219)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.markDirty(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:593)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:185)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:73)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:47)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:163)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:152)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:143)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:135)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:128)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.<init>(AbstractStateStorage.java:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.TimestampStorage.<init>(TimestampStorage.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectTimestamps.<init>(ProjectTimestamps.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:279)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам пишут в конце ошибки:

> Please perform full project rebuild (Build | Rebuild Project)

Именно это нужно сделать.